# Asterisk sip.conf in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, voip, asterisk, sip

I'm able to include a phone inside a database for realtime usage. So, this code (from `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf`):

```
[phone]
type=friend
username=phone
secret=12345
host=dynamic
disallow=all
allow=g729
allow=alaw
context=somecontext
nat=no
insecure=port,invite
```

it is now inside a database (using MySQL).

Now, I want to include a SIP trunk using the register directive, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I include `register => <username>:<password>@<provider>` inside the database as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are no way do it via realtime way you want.

- You can do via #exec directive to script which return back registration
- You can do it via usual include and script which put in text file registration one per minute(recommended)
- You can do it via storring whole file sip.conf in database(realtime static config).